# PHP Script to return wallet balance

Tags: xlm

Not sure if i'm missing something obvious but is there a simple-ish way to return a wallet balance in a php?

Just a simple return..

```
$xlmaddress = "GDS5etc";
$bal = $getBal($xlmaddress);
echo $bal; // returns balance
```

Answer (score 2):

I would simply query he horizon server using a GET request and parse the returned JSON data.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/accounts/GXXYOURADDRESS');
//return data instead of print
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
//$contents variable has the returned data now
$contents = curl_exec($ch);
//decode the json
//you can use json_decode($contents, TRUE) to make it an associative array
$result = json_decode($contents);
//print the balances
print_r($result->balances);
//
//OUTPUT:
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [balance] => 9999.9998400
            [buying_liabilities] => 0.0000000
            [selling_liabilities] => 0.0000000
            [asset_type] => native
        )

)
```

You may have multiple balances in the account, you could loop through this array.